# How to separate stormflow based on preciptation events?

Tags: time-series

I'm analyzing the response of a watershed based on daily precipitation events. Basically, each time the daily flow rises, I associate some precipitation pulses to that rise. However, sometimes due to heterogeneity of the precipitation and land use, this assumption does not work and some flow rise does not have associated rainfall. The watershed is not under snow melting. Is there any method to separate the watershed response along with its corresponding precipitation?

Thanks

Basically, each time the daily flow rises, I associate some precipitation pulses to that rise. However, this does not work for all stormflow events.